# How to separate comma from word (tokenization)

Tags: python, tokenize

I have some problem with tokenization, the assignment is to separate a sentence into words.

This is what I have done at the moment.

```
def tokenize(s):

    d = []
    start = 0
    
    while start < len(s):
        while start < len(s) and s[start].isspace():
            start = start+1

        end = start
        while end < len(s) and not s[end].isspace():
            end = end+1

        d = d + [s[start:end]]
        start = end
            
    print(d)
```

Running the program:

```
>>> tokenize("He was walking, it was fun")
['He', 'was', 'walking,', 'it', 'was', 'fun']
```

This works fine, but the problem is as you can see that my program will include the comma in the word walking. I want to separate the comma (and other "symbols") as an individual "word".

Such as:

```
['He', 'was', 'walking', ',', 'it', 'was', 'fun']
```

How can I modify my code to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your goal is to split a sentence into words, and non-alphabetical characters will be their own word, the output will be a mess from parsing a sentence like `From 1969-2009, David Peters-Foster woke up between 9:15AM and 10:15AM to go for a jog around the cul-de-sac with his neighbor's husband.`

Comment: You can use regex in these cases, like `import re` and then `print(re.findall(r'[^\W_]+|[^\w\s]|_', text))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible suggestion for a modification which will work with your specific example but which will **definitely** fail with examples like "How are you?!":

```
def tokenize(s):

    d = []
    start = 0
    
    while start < len(s):
        while start < len(s) and s[start].isspace():
            start = start+1

        end = start
        while end < len(s) and not s[end].isspace():
            end = end+1

        if(s[end-1] in ["!", ",", ".", ";", ":"]):
            d = d + [s[start:(end-1)]]
            d = d + [s[end-1]]
        else:
            d = d + [s[start:end]]
        
        start = end


            
    print(d)

tokenize("He was walking, it was fun!")
# ['He', 'was', 'walking', ',', 'it', 'was', 'fun', '!']
```

Answer (score 0):

another way to do that is using `split` function as below

```
def tokenize(s):
    d1 = s.split(",")
    d3 = []
    for d2 in d1:
        for d in d2.split():
            d3.append( d )
        d3.append( "," )
    d3.pop(-1)
    print(d3)
tokenize("He was walking, it was fun")
```